# Is a stock tethered internet connection (2.2) shareable between Linux laptops?

Tags: android, sharing, tethering

I've been casually working on this for a few months but I'm finally getting frustrated enough to post about it.

I was wondering if it was possible to share the tethered internet connection that comes stock on Android phones with 2.2 with an additional laptop? To be clear, I want to have a laptop receiving a tethered internet connection from a 2.2 Android phone and I want to share that with another laptop connected through Ethernet. Specifically, I'm trying to do this on Ubuntu Linux 10.10.

I have gotten this to work on Windows 7 using EasyTether and the Windows ICS but unfortunately I need this to work on Ubuntu Linux. Note, this really doesn't help me because  I would really like this to work as a legitimate network, when I use EasyTether to share the connection, I cannot ping the other laptop, which makes me think they are connected in a different manner besides routes. Also note, The EasyTether and Ubuntu's ICS through Network Manager does not work.

The latest thing I have tried is to set up a bridge between the phone's network interface and the 2nd laptop's interface. This allows me to ping to the phone from the second laptop. However, this disables the internet the laptop the phone is connected to and I certainly can't get on the internet on the second laptop.

So, I guess what I'm asking is: is this sort of thing even possible? If anyone has any suggestions, advice, or links, I would be glad to listen.

Comment: So you're saying that your second laptop cannot connect through the first laptop?  That's an Ubuntu problem, not an Android problem.

Comment: Very similar question here: http://superuser.com/questions/261523/ubuntu-android-sharing-a-tethered-internet-connection-of-a-phone-laptop-with

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score -1):

This sort of thing should definitely be possible, android will not be your limiting factor.

As for your computer, you may want to look into configuring iptables and/or setting up the machine receiving the tether as a gateway. The specifics of those topics are probably best discussed on https://askubuntu.com/